# Javascript: Error in Date result format

Tags: javascript, date

I try to make timer in my site.

Now i have do subtract " Now Day " with " End Day " like this :-

```
  var end = new Date( 2014 , 08 , 16 , 14 , 20 , 0 );



var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();

    var distance = end - now;


    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = '-';
        document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = '-';
        document.getElementById('h').innerHTML = '-';
        document.getElementById('s').innerHTML = '-';

        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    if(days)
    {
        document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = days;
        $("#d").parent('li').show();
    }
    document.getElementById('h').innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML = seconds;

    $(".timers").css({'visibility':'visible'});
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

The result of this operation it must be 1 day, but its show me 31 day !!

I try to alert

```
var end = new Date( 2014 , 08 , 16 , 14 , 20 , 0 );
```

it show me `Tue sep 16 2014 14:20:00 GMT +0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)`

Its Error, It must be like `Tue Agu 16 2014 14:20:00 GMT +0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)`

Why !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in JavaScript number of months starts from `0`, so if you want August, you should use `7`